# binary search to return more than one index JAVA

Tags: java, binary-search

I have the array {1,2,3,4,4,4,5}
I want my function return index of 4.
for example : 4 found at location 4,5,6

```
public void binarySearch(int value){ 
sort();  // sorting the array
int index=-1;
int lower=0;
int upper=count-1;
while(lower<=upper){
    int middle=(lower+upper)/2;

    if(value==array[middle]){
        index=middle;
        System.out.println(value+ " found at location "+(index+1));
        break;
        }
    else if(value<array[middle]){
        upper=middle-1;

    }
    else lower=middle+1;

}
```

}

Comment: why not considering creating a local List<Integer> that holds return values then returning the list? 

if(value==array[middle]){ mreturnlist.add(middle);

...

 retrun mreturnlist;

Comment: What is your code doing and how does it differ from your expected result?

Comment: @MichaelL.  my code return only first index, in this case "4 found at location 4"

Comment: @OnurEmrecanÖzcan can u send the code here ??

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard. We know that because the list is sorted, all of our indexes are going to be contiguous (next to one another). So once we've found one, we just have to traverse the list in both directions to find out what other indexes also match.

```
public static void binarySearch(int value){
    sort();
    int index = -1;
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = array.length - 1;
    while(lower <= upper){
        // The same as your code
    }

    // Create a list of indexes
    final List<Integer> indexes = new LinkedList<>();
    // Add the one we already found
    indexes.add(index);

    // Iterate upwards until we hit the end or a different value
    int current = index + 1;
    while (current < array.length && array[current] == value)
    {
        indexes.add(current);
        current++;
    }

    // Iterate downwards until we hit the start or a different value
    current = index - 1;
    while (current >= 0 && array[current] == value)
    {
        indexes.add(current);
        current--;
    }

    // Sort the indexes (do we care?)
    Collections.sort(indexes);

    for (int idx : indexes)
    {
        System.out.println(value + " found at " + (idx + 1));
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that what you have implemented is **already** a binary search. The extra code to find additional matching indexes would not fall under the usual definition of a binary search.

Comment: sorry but i forgot to mention that I should not import java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: In which case, this sounds like homework. I've given you the general idea so you can do the rest yourself. Just use an `int[]` instead of a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: yes it's a homework I did it with sequential search and it worked,
but I just can't do it with binary search, i did what u say and I got a lot of errors, and what else  can i do with Collection without import from java.util.
Can u send the completed code?

Comment: You can do a lot with `Collections`. Best place is just to [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Sorry, no. We discourage people from asking homework questions here because it doesn't help you learn. I've already given you a big clue. The rest is up to you :)